# Re rendering a component with an async function inside

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to react native and my JS is a bit rusty. I need to be able to change the value of my collection for the firestore. I have two buttons that will change the value of typeOfPost by setting the state. Component1 can successfully get "this.state.typeOfPost". However, when I click one of the buttons and update the state my log inside of the async function is not being called. It is only called when the app initially renders. What I find weird is that my log on the top of Component1 will display as expected. Is there any better way of doing this?

```
class Forum extends Component {

 state = {
    typeOfPost: ' '
 }

 onPressSitter = () => {
    this.setState({
      typeOfPost: 'sitterPosts'
      })
 }


  onPressNeedSitter = () => {
    this.setState({
      typeOfPost: 'needPosts'
      })
 }


 render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        
        <View style={styles.row}>
            <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={this.onPressSitter}
            >
            <Text>I am a sitter</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={this.onPressNeedSitter}
            >
            <Text>Need a sitter</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>

        <View>
          <Component1 typeOfPost = {this.state.typeOfPost}> </Component1>
        </View>

      </View>
    )
  }
}

const Component1 = (props) => {
  console.log("type of post " + props.typeOfPost);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); // Set loading to true on component mount
  const [data, setData] = useState([]); // Initial empty array of data
  const getData = async () => {
    console.log("type of post inside async " + props.typeOfPost);
    const subscriber = firestore()
    .collection(props.typeOfPost) // need to be able to update this
    .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
      const data = [];

      querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
        data.push({
          ...documentSnapshot.data(),
          key: documentSnapshot.id,
        });
      });

      setData(data);
      setLoading(false);
    });

    // Unsubscribe from events when no longer in use
    return () => subscriber();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, [])

  if (loading) {
    return <ActivityIndicator />;
  }

  return (
      <FlatList
      data={data}
      ListEmptyComponent={
          <View style={styles.flatListEmpty}>
              <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>No Data</Text>
          </View>
      }
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View>
            <Text>User ID: {item.fullName}</Text>
          </View>
      )}
  />
  )
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using react hook useCallback it works for this kind of stuffs.

Comment: First off, I don't see any await. Why do you have an async?

Comment: I thought the query to firebase is an asynchronous action? @jperl

Comment: Yes, but there is a callback. So there's no need for async.

`const subscriber = await firestore()...` would be another story.

Comment: good to know. Have you got anymore useful tips?

Comment: also you should call setLoading(true) before the call to firestore (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between `mount` and `render`. I see no problem with your code except the few remarks I have made. The thing is that when you change `typeOfPost`, the component is rerendered, but the useEffect is not called again, since you said, it's just called when it was first mounted:

```
useEffect(() => {

}, []) // ---> [] says to run only when first mounted
```

However here, you want it to run whenever `typeOfPost` changes. So here is how you can do this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, [typeofPost])
```

```
class Forum extends Component {

 state = {
    typeOfPost: ' '
 }

 onPressSitter = () => {
    this.setState({
      typeOfPost: 'sitterPosts'
      })
 }


  onPressNeedSitter = () => {
    this.setState({
      typeOfPost: 'needPosts'
      })
 }


 render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        
        <View style={styles.row}>
            <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={this.onPressSitter}
            >
            <Text>I am a sitter</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={this.onPressNeedSitter}
            >
            <Text>Need a sitter</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>

        <View>
          <Component1 typeOfPost = {this.state.typeOfPost}> </Component1>
        </View>

      </View>
    )
  }
}

const Component1 = (props) => {
  const { typeOfPost } = props 
  console.log("type of post " + props.typeOfPost);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); // Set loading to true on component mount
  const [data, setData] = useState([]); // Initial empty array of data
  const getData = () => {
    setLoading(true)
    console.log("type of post inside async " + props.typeOfPost);
    const subscriber = firestore()
    .collection(props.typeOfPost) // need to be able to update this
    .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
      const data = [];

      querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
        data.push({
          ...documentSnapshot.data(),
          key: documentSnapshot.id,
        });
      });

      setData(data);
      setLoading(false);
    });

    // Unsubscribe from events when no longer in use
    return () => subscriber();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, [typeofPost])

  if (loading) {
    return <ActivityIndicator />;
  }

  return (
      <FlatList
      data={data}
      ListEmptyComponent={
          <View style={styles.flatListEmpty}>
              <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>No Data</Text>
          </View>
      }
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View>
            <Text>User ID: {item.fullName}</Text>
          </View>
      )}
  />
  )
}
```

Comment: I actually just figured this out myself

Comment: thanks to @Phemieny007 telling me to look into hooks

Answer (score 0):

1. you are using a class based component to access react hook which is a bad practice, i will advice you use a functional component and you have access to react useCallback hook which will handle your request easily

```
const ButtonPressed = useCallback(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        getData()
        }).then(() => setLoading(false));
    }, [loading]);
```

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly pretty much just change component 1 to a function then I can use these hooks?

Comment: Yes and try do some code clean up as well

Comment: There was no such thing as hooks in the class though. There is a class component and a functional component.

Comment: @jperl can you elaborate?